# c++ VS17 - GL window blank and title is solution name

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew, glm-math

I'm following a fairly simple tutorial and all the files compile, and I am using openGL, glew, and glfw in my current code. The window is not displaying correctly and I don't think it's even displaying. I have my main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Libs.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 

    glfwInit();

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 640;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480;
int FRAME_BUFFER_WIDTH = 0;
int FRAME_BUFFER_HEIGHT = 0;

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); 

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "Custom Name", NULL, NULL);

glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &FRAME_BUFFER_WIDTH, &FRAME_BUFFER_HEIGHT);
glViewport(0, 0, FRAME_BUFFER_WIDTH, FRAME_BUFFER_HEIGHT);

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

if (glfwInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    std::cout << "GLFW INIT != GL_OK \n";
    glfwTerminate();
}

//Main loop

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

    glfwPollEvents();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glFlush();
}

glfwTerminate();
return 1;

}
```

and my Libs.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <vec2.hpp>
#include <vec3.hpp>
#include <vec4.hpp>
#include <mat4x4.hpp>
#include <gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <SOIL2.h>
```

The whole thing compiles just fine and opens without any errors. I can't see any of the console text that I'm displaying (std::cout) as I'm running in visual studio.
The problem is when it opens, the window is displayed like this: [Window that's displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t96Fo.png)

As you can see, the window is completely blank and there is no green (which it should be). Also, the window name is my solution name and not the one that I gave it ("Custom Name"). Lastly, the icon for the window is a package, which I think means that it's not GL but rather Visual Studio making it. I have no idea why this is happening and no errors are occurring.

If anyone has a possible fix that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Haven't used this before but I'm pretty sure cout wouldn't print to the window you create. Also, I recall having a problem in VS with small programs where the console would open, the program would run, and the console would close within milliseconds since the program completed. Try adding a getch to the end of main to make sure this isn't what's going on.

Comment: Didn't seem to do anything, no console appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:
Pretty simple, I made my project with extra files already there. I needed to make it from an empty project, hopefully this can help somebody in the future.